# Dua's in sujood

Tags: salat, dua, sujud

Assalamualaikum,

I want to do longer sujoods. This is because I want to feel more connected to Allah(swt) in my prayers. In my sujoods, can I recite dua's. For example can I recite, "Hasbi Allahu wa ni'mal wakeel" while in sujood?

JazakAllah Khairan!

Comment: You can recite any dua in Sujood. What’s the issue?

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile ok thanks I was just confused on doing it in obligatory prayers or sunnah

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and even all the doas you do in your sujood are inshallah answered and that is from what the prophet [pbuh] said

> “the nearest a servant comes to his Lord is when he is prostrating himself, so make supplication (in this state)” (Saheeh Bukhari).

Hope that answers your question
Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

You can make your sujood longer using below invocations proven from sunnah.

Number 1

> Abu Musa al-Ash’ari (RAA) narrated, “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used
> to supplicate,'Rabbi-ghfir-li Khati 'ati wa jahli wa israfi fi `Amri
> kullihi, wa ma anta a'lamu bihi minni. Allahumma ighfirli khatayaya wa
> 'amdi, wa jahli wa jiddi, wa kullu dhalika'indi. Allahumma ighrifli ma
> qaddamtu wa ma akhartu wa ma asrartu wa ma a'lantu. Anta-l-muqaddimu
> wa anta-l-mu'akh-khiru, wa anta 'ala kulli shai'in qadir.' “O Allah,
> forgive me my faults, my ignorance, my immoderation in my concern. And
> you are better aware (of my affairs) than myself. O Allah, grant me
> forgiveness (of the faults which I committed) seriously or otherwise
> (and which I committed) inadvertently and deliberately. All these
> (failings) are in me. O Allah, grant me forgiveness from the faults,
> which I did in haste or deferred, which I committed in privacy or in
> public and you are better aware (of them) than myself. You are the
> First and the Last and over all things you are Omnipotent.” Agreed
> Upon.
>
> English reference : Book 16, Hadith 1606
> Arabic reference : Book 16, Hadith 1563(2819)

Number 2

> Allaahumma laka sajadtu wa bika 'aamantu, wa laka 'aslamtu, sajada
> wajhiya lillathee khalaqahu, wa sawwarahu, wa shaqqa sam'ahu wa
> basarahu, tabaarakallaahu 'ahsanul-khaaliqeen.
>
> O Allah, to You I prostrate myself and in You I believe. To You I have
> submitted. My face is prostrated to the One Who created it, fashioned
> it, and gave it hearing and sight. Blessed is Allah, the Best of
> creators.
> Reference: Muslim 1/534

Number 3

> Allaahum-maghfir lee thanbee kullahu, diqqahu wa jillahu, wa 'awwalahu
> wa 'aakhirahu wa 'alaaniyata hu wa sirrahu.
>
> O Allah, forgive me all my sins, great and small, the first and the
> last, those that are apparent and those that are hidden.
>
> Reference: Muslim 1/350.

Number 4

> Allaahumma 'innee 'a'oothu biridhaaka min sakhatika, wa bimu'aafaatika
> min 'uqoobatika wa 'a'oothu bika minka, laa 'uhsee thanaa'an 'alayka
> 'Anta kamaa 'athnayta 'alaa nafsika.
>
> O Allah, I seek protection in Your pleasure from Your anger, and I
> seek protection in Your forgiveness from Your punishment. I seek
> protection in You from You. I cannot count Your praises. You are as
> You have praised Yourself.
>
> Reference: Muslim 1/352.